# SVN: move a file and then add a file with the old name

Tags: svn, refactoring

I'm working on refactoring a C++ code tree versioned with `SVN`. The current code has 2 classes, say `Model` and `Model_ext` (each with a `.hh` file and a `.cpp` file) that do not derive from each other. `Model` was not supposed to be extended but it implements a specific model.

I wanted to create an abstract base class but the more logical name for this one is `Model`. Code specific to the model implemented in the current `Model` should be move in a class called `Model_A` that derives from it. Similarly, `Model_ext` should be renamed `Model_B` but this is not the problem.

From a version control point of view, I wanted to move `Model` to `Model_A` with:

```
svn mv Model.cpp Model_A.cpp
```

(and similarly for the header file) in order to indicate that `Model_A.cpp` is the new version of `Model.cpp` (and it will have local modifications).

Of course I also have to add the new `Model.cpp`. Is it possible or will it confuse `SVN`?

I know that it is possible to modify `Model.cpp`, add `Model_A.cpp` (without using `svn mv`) and commit both files but this would destroy all link between the old `Model.cpp` and the new `Model_A.cpp`.

Comment: Commit after the move & before the you add the new `Model.cpp` and it will be fine.

Comment: Sure but then the intermediate revision would not compile (because the base class is not there) and I try to avoid that.

Comment: Well, don't compile it then. Continuous integration has it's limits, and trunk is not the place to play around, that happens in branches...  However, I did a quick test for you, svn v.1,6 commits the replaced file just fine, but older versions may have problems in my (possibly flawed) recollection.

Comment: It works here (tm). Then again, may be a Linux vs. Windows thing, or a TortoiseSVN thing (you might want to try the command line svn tools). An `svn mv` removes the file immediately from it's original location here, and I can just create & add a new one...

Comment: You right it works here too with the command-line svn tools (tm)! I was using kdesvn (under linux). I'm surprised it don't allow me to do that but that's not the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried the following...

```
$ svn move file.txt new.file.txt
A         new.file.txt
D         file.txt
$ vi file.txt
$ svn add file.txt
A         file.txt
$ svn status
R         file.txt
A         new.file.txt
$ svn commit -m"test"
Replacing      file.txt
Adding         new.file.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 5.
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes we figured that out (see comments in my question).

Comment: In Subversion, the new `file.txt` is a completely new file and not just a newer revision of the old `file.txt. Take the history and see. I bet that confuses the bejeebers out of the kdesvn client because that doesn't track renames.